# Use enum to select string from wicket properties file

Tags: properties, enums, internationalization, wicket

I'd like to add a label to a wicket panel where the label's model is an enum value.  Based on the value of that enum, I'd like to display a different message pulled from the page's properties file.

For example, here's an enum:

```
public enum ApprovalType { UNAPPROVED, APPROVED, BLOCKED };
```

I can easily add a label to the panel that has this enum as its model:

```
add(new Label("approval", new Model(ApprovalType.APPROVED)));
```

However, this will simply output UNAPPROVED, APPROVED, or BLOCKED. I'd like to output a localized message that is selected based on the value of this enum.

So if I have this properties file, what's the best way to get these messages to output?

```
UNAPPROVED=Your membership is currently pending approval
APPROVED=Your membership has been approved
BLOCKED=You have been blocked from membership
```

I can get it working like this:

```
add(new Label("approval", new ResourceModel(ApprovalType.APPROVED.name());
```

But the problem is that ResourceModel only accepts a string (resource key).  I'd like to pull the value of the resource key automatically from a model (preferrably a CompoundPropertyModel). In other words, I don't want to do this:

```
Member member = (Member) getDefaultModelObject();
add(new Label("approval", new ResourceModel(member.getApproval().name())));
```

I'd rather do something like:

```
add(new EnumLabel("approval");  // assuming I have a CompoundPropertyModel
```

Is there a component that does this that comes with Wicket?  Or do I need to write my own?

Lastly, I discovered this also works:

```
add(new Label("approval", new StringResourceModel(
    "${}", 
    new PropertyModel<ApprovalType>(getDefaultModel(),"approval")
)));
```

But this seems overly verbose, and still doesn't utilize the simplicity of using CompoundPropertyModel.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this 'll work, but maybe you could try writing your own EnumModel class that takes the value of an Enum and returns a ResourceModel value..

Please say so if the above isn't clear enough, I'll try to elaborate.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the right direction to go.  I found a detailed example (http://wicketbyexample.com/enums-internationalization-with-wicket/) of using enums and internationalization that goes over this specific problem. But the solution is so verbose, I was really looking for something lighter weight.  If you could elaborate on your EnumModel, it would help.

Comment: The EnumPropertyModel mentioned in the article you're referring to comes pretty close to what I would have tried.. Are you sure it can't be simplified/made to work with a CompoundPropertyModel? I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of Wicket to know if this is possible at all..